# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters' when django-filter is installed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when I try to start my django app by running `python manage.py runserver`
I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'` however I have installed django-filter using `pip install django-filter`and added `'django_filters'` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` as the documentation says. So I'm having a hard time figuring out what's causing this issue. I appreciate any help.

Here is my `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'students.apps.StudentsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_filters',
    'crispy_forms',
]
```

and these are the packages I have

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
asgiref             3.3.4
Django              3.1.3
django-cors-headers 3.3.0
django-crispy-forms 1.10.0
django-filter       2.4.0
djangorestframework 3.11.0
pip                 21.1.2
pytz                2021.1
setuptools          46.0.0
sqlparse            0.4.1
wheel               0.34.2
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: It's possible that the `pip` script you are running is not installing modules for the interpreter that the `python` command is using. Trying using `python -m pip install django-filter` instead

Comment: Are you working on a virtual environment?

Comment: Install virtual env file and install all packages

Comment: ```python -m pip install django-filter``` solved the issue thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```bash
pip install django-filter
```